# How do I render HTML in polymer that is retrieved from json?

Tags: html, polymer

When I initialize my app, I grab json file that contains all the content. Some of the content contains html markup. When rendered out through the template:

{{question.text}}

it shows the html as literal a string.

How can I get this to display as html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already written an element for this. [Juicy html](https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-html) should be able to do it

Comment: LOL, I literally just found that and it works great. I used it to create an easier element as well. <html-string>{{content}}</html-string>